# Clarification on Ruby class method

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I found this class from Eloquent Ruby book.

```
class TextCompressor
  attr_reader :unique, :index
  def initialize( text )
    @unique = []
    @index = []
    words = text.split
    words.each do |word|
      i = @unique.index( word )
      if i
        @index << i
      else
        @unique << word
        @index << unique.size - 1
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

It works like this:

```
text = "This specification is the spec for a specification"
compressor = TextCompressor.new(text)
compressor.unique #=> ["This", "specification", "is", "the", "spec", "for", "a"]
compressor.index #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
```

1. What is `unique` in `@index << unique.size - 1`, and where did it get its value from?
2. Are `compressor.unique` and `compressor.index` coming from `attr_reader :unique, :index`, or `@unique` and `@index`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In the context of the `initialize` method the `unique` is the same as `self.unique` and the `self` here is the instantiated object (`TextCompressor.new`)

`self.unique` in this case will return you the value of `@unique` variable

2. The reason you can call `compressor.unique` and `compressor.index` is coming from `attr_reader :unique, :index`.
   This line sets getters for you (getter is a method to query object for instance variable value).

Comment: Thanks for answering them! I need further clarification on #1: Is it correct to say that `:unique` gets its value from `@unique`, that this is possible because of Ruby's magic as long as `@my_var` is named the same as `attr_reader :my_var`?

Comment: Yes @Iggy. This is correct. Ruby magic "connecting" for you `@my_var` and getter method defined by line `attr_reader :my_var`. Even more, if you for example define getter and setter with line `attr_accessor :some_name` ruby will actually create for you the variable `@some_name` at the moment you'll assign some value to it through the setter method (and you can use this variable accessing to it with `@some_name` in your class).

Answer (score 1):

The `@unique` and `@index` are private instance variables. Inside the class, you always precede them with an `@`. Outside the class, they are completely unavailable<sup>[1]</sup>. `attr_reader` is a metaprogramming function in Ruby that constructs a getter. The following are equivalent.

```
attr_reader :unique, :index
```

and

```
def unique
  @unique
end

def index
  @index
end
```

The methods defined by `attr_reader` and co are public and thus can be accessed outside the class, using `object_name.unique` syntax. Like in many languages, they can also be accessed unqualified from within the class, so if you're inside the class scope, `unique` and `self.unique` will evaluate to the same thing (assuming there isn't a local variable called `unique` in scope). So your `unique.size` call is actually calling two methods. In Java, it would look like `getUnique().getSize()`, but Ruby lets us omit the parentheses in many cases.

An important thing to remember about Ruby is that, in general, if you do `a.b` or `a.b = c`, you are *always* calling a method. Ruby instance variables (the things starting with `@`) are always private, so there's no way to directly access them outside the class. There's no `foo.bar` syntax to access a public instance variable like in Java or C++. `foo.bar` is always a method; it just might happen to be a method which accesses and returns the value of `@bar`.

This is more in line with Smalltalk's view of OOP, where loosely coupled objects pass messages in order to exchange information. In such a model, it doesn't make sense to have direct access to someone else's data; all you can do is request it and wait for the response.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Ignoring reflection features, which can bypass such rules.

Comment: 1. Even when there are no getters we can always use [Object#instance_varaible_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) to obtain values of instance variables. 2. The OP made no mention of Java or Smalltalk and (like me) may know nothing of either. Why even mention them? 3. [Module#attr_reader](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) is a garden-variety Ruby method that merely saves us the trouble of writing getters. Why bring up metaprogramming, which is unnecessary and certainly beyond many readers' knowledge.